# Accidentally zoomed in the whole interface to 20

Tags: visual-studio-code

I accidentally zommed in the vscode whole interface to 20. Now, I can't find any way to zoom out that. What to do?
I tried reinstalling the vscode after unistalling all of its footprint
Please help me

Comment: Try `Ctrl+-` might help.  That is `Ctrl` with a `-` at the same time.

Comment: Even this is not working

Comment: Pressing ctrl+0 made the things simple. Thanks!